# Set Throttle property with name property in single route

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am presently using below code in route in Laravel 8.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Annonymous\Login\API\LoginAPIController;
Route::post('/authenticate', [LoginAPIController::class, "authenticateUser"])->name("apiAuthenticateUser");
```

Like there is name property, Is there any way to set middleware also for throttle along with name property? Something like this?

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Annonymous\Login\API\LoginAPIController;
Route::post('/authenticate', [LoginAPIController::class, "authenticateUser"])->name("apiAuthenticateUser")->throttle("10, 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, throttle is a middleware so you would do the following

```
Route::post('/authenticate', [LoginAPIController::class, "authenticateUser"])->name("apiAuthenticateUser")->middleware('throttle:10, 1');
```